# MySQL QUOTE function returning Japanese (Mojibake)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

The QUOTE function is sometimes returning jibberish, instead of the expected behavior.  Please see below.  Any help or insight you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Below QUOTE returns NULL, as expected...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "select QUOTE(GL_CODE), QUOTE(GL_DESC) from CHARGE_TYPE where TERMINATE_DATE is null limit 5;"
+----------------+----------------+
| QUOTE(GL_CODE) | QUOTE(GL_DESC) |
+----------------+----------------+
| NULL           | NULL           |
| NULL           | NULL           |
| NULL           | NULL           |
| NULL           | NULL           |
| NULL           | NULL           |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Here are the charsets...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';"                                                       
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Here are the collations...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';"    
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

And here's the collation for the CHARGE_TYPE table...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "SELECT TABLE_COLLATION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CHARGE_TYPE';"
+-------------------+
| TABLE_COLLATION   |
+-------------------+
| latin1_swedish_ci |
+-------------------+
```

Below QUOTE returns Japanese characters instead of NULL...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "select QUOTE(GL_CODE), QUOTE(GL_DESC) from CHARGE_TYPE where TERMINATE_DATE is null limit 5;"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+----------------+----------------+
| QUOTE(GL_CODE) | QUOTE(GL_DESC) |
+----------------+----------------+
| 乕䱌           | 乕䱌           |
| 乕䱌           | 乕䱌           |
| 乕䱌           | 乕䱌           |
| 乕䱌           | 乕䱌           |
| 乕䱌           | 乕䱌           |
+----------------+----------------+
```

Here are the charsets...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';"                                                       
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                          |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                         |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                        |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql-8.0/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Here are the collations...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';"                                                           
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

And, here's the collation for the CHARGE_TYPE table...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "SELECT TABLE_COLLATION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'CHARGE_TYPE';"
+------------------+
| TABLE_COLLATION  |
+------------------+
| utf16_general_ci |
+------------------+
```

I know that the columns contain nulls...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "select HEX(GL_CODE), HEX(GL_DESC) from CHARGE_TYPE where TERMINATE_DATE is null limit 5;"
+--------------+--------------+
| HEX(GL_CODE) | HEX(GL_DESC) |
+--------------+--------------+
| NULL         | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL         |
+--------------+--------------+
```

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "select ISNULL(GL_CODE), ISNULL(GL_DESC) from CHARGE_TYPE where TERMINATE_DATE is null limit 5;"
+-----------------+-----------------+
| ISNULL(GL_CODE) | ISNULL(GL_DESC) |
+-----------------+-----------------+
|               1 |               1 |
|               1 |               1 |
|               1 |               1 |
|               1 |               1 |
|               1 |               1 |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

The version is 8.0.32...

```
mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "SELECT @@version;"                                                                      
+-----------+
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 8.0.32    |
+-----------+
```

MORE INFORMATION:

If the table is created with `CHARSET=latin1`, then QUOTE works as expected....

```
CREATE TABLE CHARGE_TYPE (
...
...
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

If the table is created with `CHARSET=utf16`, then QUOTE doesn't work properly...

```
CREATE TABLE CHARGE_TYPE (
...
...
...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16;
```

UPDATE:

Bug opened with MySQL: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=110672

```
CREATE TABLE LATIN1_TABLE (
  COLUMN1 varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO LATIN1_TABLE (COLUMN1) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO LATIN1_TABLE (COLUMN1) VALUES ('NOTNULL');

SELECT QUOTE(COLUMN1) FROM LATIN1_TABLE; -- returns NULL, and 'NOTNULL' as expected.

CREATE TABLE UTF16_TABLE (
  COLUMN1 varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf16;

INSERT INTO UTF16_TABLE (COLUMN1) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO UTF16_TABLE (COLUMN1) VALUES ('NOTNULL');

SELECT QUOTE(COLUMN1) FROM UTF16_TABLE; -- returns Japanese/Mojibake and 'NOTNULL'.
```

Comment: It's worth checking what's in this column in raw `HEX(...)` form.

Comment: @tadman returns NULL in both cases...

```
 mysql -f -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -urms -prms rms -e "select HEX(GL_CODE), HEX(GL_DESC) from CHARGE_TYPE where TERMINATE_DATE is null limit 5;"
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+--------------+--------------+
| HEX(GL_CODE) | HEX(GL_DESC) |
+--------------+--------------+
| NULL         | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL         |
| NULL         | NULL         |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: You tagged it as `mariadb` and `mariadb-10.5` but select @@version returns `8.0.32` which is MySQL! MariaDB and MySQL are not the same!

Comment: @hobby_programmer true, but they are similar and was hoping that some mariadb folks could help here also.

Comment: @hobby_programmer actually it looks like someone removed the mysql tag...strange...I just added it back.

Comment: Why do you think the column doesn't contain those Japanese strings? What do you see if you don't call `QUOTE()`?

Comment: @Barmar the columns contain nulls.

Comment: @Barmar edited to show proof columns contain null values.